# Displaying key/value in PHP object

Tags: php

In PHP, how can I make this data:

```
{
   "items": {
     "item": [{
           "id": "59",
           "type": "Domain",
           "relid": "27",
           "description": "Sample Monthly Product(01\ / 01\ / 2016 - 31\ / 01\ / 2016)",
           "amount": "180.00",
           "taxed": "0"
      }]
   }
}
```

Have this format:

```
{
  "items[item][0][id]": "59",
  "items[item][0][type]": "Domain",
  "items[item][0][relid]": "27",
  "items[item][0][description]": "Sample Monthly Product (01\/01\/2016 - 31\/01\/2016)",
  "items[item][0][amount]": "180.00",
  "items[item][0][taxed]": "0"
}
```

Reason: Setting up a Zap (via Zapier) using email parser to import invoices from WHMCS, and it seems to work with parsing data when 2nd format (items[item][0][id]) to read the line descriptions but not when using the 1st. In the WHMCS API ref it shows it outputting as the 2nd format but can't see why mine looks like 1st (developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getinvoice)

Comment: Do you really want your key to be: `"items[item][0][id]"`? That's just...  weird.

Comment: Why would you want to. It almost already is what you want anyway

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! First, you have an `object`, not an `array`. Second, your object is riddled with syntax errors. Can you please ensure that the information is correct? Third, **why** are you trying to restructure like this? Your data is already in a format that is highly accessible. Are you just trying to affix a `[0]` index? Assuming you're running this in a loop, you can just use a `foreach`.

Comment: Setting up a Zap (via Zapier) using email parser to import invoices from WHMCS, and it seems to work with 2nd format (items[item][0][id]) to read the line descriptions but not when using the 1st. 
In the WHMCS API ref it shows it outputting as the 2nd format but can't see why mine looks like 1st (https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getinvoice/)

Comment: If you scroll down to the [**Example Response JSON**](https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getinvoice/) you can see what the API is expecting. Converting just requires two for loops to flatten the array.

Comment: I did scroll down and see that. Which is why was bit unsure on how they could use that example code (using CURL or Local API) to then output Response JSON in that format. As both ways tested when using print_r or  var_dump it didn't end up looking like "items[item][0][id]", so assumed there must be way without having to use foreach like you showed in your answer.

Comment: It's too bad that the API you're using requires this sort of backwards format. Does it work though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might work with your current setup:

```
<?php

//assuming your current dataset isn't in JSON, you can ignore this part
$json = '{
   "items": {
     "item": [{
           "id": "59",
           "type": "Domain",
           "relid": "27",
           "description": "Sample Monthly Product",
           "amount": "180.00",
           "taxed": "0"
      },
      {
           "id": "203",
           "type": "Server",
           "relid": "86",
           "description": "Sample Yearly Product",
           "amount": "290.00",
           "taxed": "1"
      }]
   }
}';

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$parsed = array();

foreach ($json['items']['item'] as $index => $item)
    foreach ($item as $attr => $val)
        $parsed['items[item][' . $index . '][' . $attr . ']'] = $val;

echo json_encode($parsed);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/9760cd4a98797e):

```
{
    "items[item][0][id]": "59",
    "items[item][0][type]": "Domain",
    "items[item][0][relid]": "27",
    "items[item][0][description]": "Sample Monthly Product",
    "items[item][0][amount]": "180.00",
    "items[item][0][taxed]": "0",
    "items[item][1][id]": "203",
    "items[item][1][type]": "Server",
    "items[item][1][relid]": "86",
    "items[item][1][description]": "Sample Yearly Product",
    "items[item][1][amount]": "290.00",
    "items[item][1][taxed]": "1"
}
```